# How to convert objects inside array to nested array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array containing objects that every element but the last one are objects, but I want to convert them into an array of arrays and add the last element.

To be more explicit here is how I have it:

```
[
    { 0: [1,2], 1: [6,2], name: "" },
    { 0: [3,4], 1: [2,2], name: "" }
]
```

and the result I want is this one:

```
[
    { multipolygon: [ [1,2], [6,2] ], name: ""},
    { multipolygon: [ [3,4], [2,2] ], name: ""}
]
```

Each single array contained inside the original array is converted into an array of those arrays.

I have tried doing this:

```js
const zonesArray = zones.map(el => Object.values(el)) // obj => array
const polygons = zonesArray.filter(el => el.pop()) // array without name
```

to get all the arrays contained inside the obj but then I realized how can I replace this into the original objects.

I have tried to modify the groupBy function found on MDN:

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    let key = obj[property]
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push(obj)
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

But I can't seem to find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're trying to group *by* a property, you're trying to transform each object in the array separately - which can be done by taking the `name` and the numeric properties together when mapping, then returning the shape of the new object:

```js
const arr = [
    { 0: [1,2], 1: [6,2], name: "" },
    { 0: [3,4], 1: [2,2], name: "" }
];

const result = arr.map(({ name, ...rest }) => ({
  name,
  multipolygon: Object.values(rest)
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I meant to say that I have tried to modify the group by function to my expected result but didn't worked. 
Can you explain me how it works?

Comment: The destructured `name` takes the `name` property from the object being mapped over. The `...rest` collects the rest of the properties (the numeric ones) into an object. Then return a new object with the `name`, and the `multipolygon` as the values of the rest object.

Comment: Elegant solution.